# How to select QTableView row based on my Sqlite Query?

Tags: sql, select, selection, qtableview, qsqltablemodel

My application is a two window application, where in one of them you can change the position and mark points that are added to my SQL DB, and the other where you can view the marked point.

I've got a `QTableView` with a`QSqlTableModel`.
The model is connected to a table named `t_point` with the following columns:

- id integer PRIMARY KEY
- position integer

What i want to do is the following: 
click on the table in one window and automatically move to the position on the other. ( this is done )

Move the position and automatically select in the `QTableView` the item with the nearest position.
Here is the deal, i want to do it fast and clean. So i use a `QSqlQuery` to get the closest item with the following query:

```
QString("SELECT position FROM t_point ORDER BY ABS(position - %1);").arg(actualPosition);
```

and so a i have them ordered by the distance from the point, i use `query.next()` and i get the two values. index and position.

So now how do i select the `QTableView` row mend to this values?

I cant use `selectRow( int row )  from QTableView` because i don't have a row, i got the key and the position...

The only solution that I've got was to look out for my id or position on the Model. But that's terrible.